# Does anyone knows the SmartGen LINK Port protocol?

Tags: ttl

I need to replace an [SG72A](http://smartgen-america.com/catalog/products/interface-adapters-and-cables/smartgen-sg72a-pc-adaptor-usb-rs232-rs485-link/) controller in a machine, I would like to make a cable or small component to It, because I have no time to wait for this to came from China to Brazil.

I didn't found any information about the protocol used by this LINK port, the only thing is that it´s a TTL level port, witch doesn't say to much for me. Can anyone help me with some link or any information?

Comment: From their doc: *LINK Smartgen special port. Communicate with controller which produced by Smartgen* - I read it like "This is a proprietary protocol we are not going to tell you how it works".

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah, so It´s not just me having this understanding about it...